# 301 redirect to new domain and redirect individual old pages at the same time

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, concrete5

I hope you can help me with this 301 issue.

**Introduction**

I've just published a re-design of a website with new clean urls. The old webpage had urls like this: *www.domain.dk/Default.aspx?ID=66*. And the new website urls look like this: *www.domain.com/contact*

So I wan't to redirect all these old urls to the new ones, and therefor i'm not keeping the old urls and no general rule can be applied.

That's just simple 301 redirects, but at the same time the old domain points to a new domain, and this is where things get dirty, I think. The old domain was www.domain.dk, but i wan't to 301 all traffic to the new domain www.domain.com and at the same time I wan't to make all the individual 301 redirects.

**The problem**

When I click on the link *www.domain.dk/Default.aspx?ID=66* in Google I get this URL in my *browser: www.domain.comindex.php/?ID=66*.

On other links I get *www.domain.comdefault.aspx/?ID=2*

So the redirecting to the new domain works fine? But the individual redirects doesn't apply at all.

**The code**

This code is pasted as is from my .htaccess file on the server running apache.

The first bit is auto-generated by Concrete5 CMS to make pretty URLs.

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

This is the code I found to 301 redirect all traffic to urls that is **not** using www.esvagt.com to www.esvagt.com

```
## --- 301 Redirects --- ##

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is just one of the manual 301 redirects.

```
## General - Redirects ##

redirect 301 /Default.aspx?ID=66 http://www.domain.com/contact/contact-us
```

Thanks in advance. If you need more information I'll gladly provide that.
I have **zero** knowledge about writing code in .htaccess, so I'm pretty clueless. I hope you can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid mixing `mod_rewrite` and `mod_alias` rules.
2. Ordering of rules is also very important so have 301 rules first and then have your catch all controller rule

Use this code for 301 redirect:

```
## --- 301 Redirects --- ##

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## General - Redirects ##

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+Default\.aspx\?ID=66[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/contact/contact-us? [R=301,L]

# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! I'll try that immediately. Should i write the old domain ending on .dk on the 2nd line and the new domain ending on .com on the 3rd line? Or should they both be .com?

Comment: see edit, now you can just replace `.dk` and `.com` domain names accordingly in first rule.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Pasted the code you have provided and changed all domain names to the right ones. However that redirect to http://www.domain.com/contact/contact-us did not work. I still get http://www.domain.comindex.php/?ID=66 in the browser.

Comment: Aha. Works perfectly in Safari. So it will take some time for it to work in Chrome (the browser I normally use)? I have about 80 redirects in total. How and where would I write them?

Comment: In chrome you can just clear your browser cache. You can write those redirects just below `## General - Redirects ##` section as I have shown above. Alternatively if you have access to Apache config you can make use `RewriteMap` feature.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for asking stupid questions, but I have zero htaccess knowledge, so I need to understand this right, as it is a problem I'm often facing. :) I'm confused where the rewritecond under ## General - Redirects ## picks up the right ID and sent it to the right url in the rule right under. Where does it pick up exactly id 66, which was the old contact page? Should I have both a condition and a rule for every redirect and how do I specify which ID leads to which URL?

Comment: @user2412263: Not you fault, I didn't use `ID=66` in my answer earlier. I edited my code, you can see how I am matching `Default.aspx\?ID=66` and redirecting it to `contact/contact-us` under the **`## General - Redirects ## section`**

Comment: Alright. Cool. I got it now. Looks like everything works. Thanks a lot for your quick responses. I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: I need to have the overall redirect and some specific ones to specific pages.  How would that work in this case?
like: `Redirect 301 old-url https://new-url`

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule ^old_url https://new-url [L,NC,NE,R=301]` just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule `www.domain.dk/Default.aspx?ID=66 domain.com/contact/contact-us [R=301,L]`

If you want to redirect all posts automatically:

```
RewriteRule /Artical.aspx?ID=(.+?) domain.com/article-title-$1.html [R=301,L]
or
RewriteRule /Artical.aspx?ID=(.+?) domain.com/Post.aspx?ID=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then the dynamic url `Artical.aspx?ID=20` will be redirect to `http://www.domain.com/article-title-30.html`,
I successfully apply this method for my blog http://downloadapp.info